# How to connect to Facebook like Zoho does in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, openid

Pretty much all the tutorials I found on authenticating users using Facebook, make use of a new window which I find to be an ugly solution. But [www.zoho.com](http://www.zoho.com/) on the other hand does this much like the way that OpenID works. Can someone tell give detailed instructions on how **Zoho** does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a full page redirect mode but it's their "legacy" API.  Their newer one is the popup style that you dislike.  Their *newest* one is OAuth 2.0, which is back to the full page redirect from what I've seen.

DotNetOpenAuth 3.5, when it ships, will include OAuth 2.0 support and a Facebook login sample.  Slated for at least a few weeks out before it's released though.

Comment: That's very interesting because I'm already using the DotNetOpenAuth 3.4 for OpenId integration. Do you have ideas about when the new release is due to come out?

Comment: Likely a few weeks out.  But if you don't mind beta quality, Facebook integration via OAuth 2.0 is working today in DNOA's oauthWRAP branch.